# Почему при вызове метода класса для одного блока он применяться одновременн и для других?

Tags: javascript, ооп, классы

При нажатии на фигуру срабатывает метод класса move() и в зависимости от нажатых кнопок она перемещается, если после перемещений первой фигуры начать перемещать вторую фигуру то они начинают двигаться вместе.

Как сделать чтобы они не двигались вместе, подскажите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
class Figure {
  constructor(type, name, styles) {
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
    this.styles = styles;
  }

  createFigure() {
    
    this.element = document.createElement('div');
    this.element.classList.add('el', `${this.type}`);
    this.element.style = `${this.css(this.styles)}`;
    this.element.dataset.name = this.name;

    this.element.addEventListener('click', () => this.move());

    let content = document.querySelector('#content');
    content.append(this.element);

  }

  move() {
    
    let y = 0;
    let x = 0;
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      
      const keyCode = event.code;
      
      switch (keyCode) {
        case 'ArrowDown':
          y++;
          this.element.style.top = y + 'px';
          break;
        case 'ArrowUp':
          y--;
          this.element.style.top = y + 'px';
          break;
        case 'ArrowLeft':
          x--;
          this.element.style.left = x + 'px';
          break;
        case 'ArrowRight':
          x++;
          this.element.style.left = x + 'px';
          break;
      }
    });
  }

  css(styles = {}) {
    if (typeof styles === 'string') return styles;
    return Object.keys(styles).map(key => `${key}: ${styles[key]}`).join(';');
  }

}

let a = new Figure('circle', 'Круг', {
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px',
    'border-radius': '50px',
    background: 'lightblue'
  }
);

let b = new Figure('square', 'Квадрат', {
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px',
    background: '#cccccc'
  }
);

a.createFigure();
b.createFigure();
```

```css
    #content {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .el {
        position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="panel"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уф, пришлось ваш код перелопатить, чтобы он стал работоспособным тут :)

одновременно у вас объекты двигаются по причине, что когда вы нажимаете на объект и вызывается метод `move` внутри этого метода вы вешаете новое событие

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
```

таким образом у вас не происходит переключение с одного объекта на другой - типа что событие работает только для одного объекта

происходит следующее:

1. если нажать на стрелку вправо, то ни один объект не двигается
2. если нажать на круг, то будет добавлено событие на нажатие кнопки для круга
3. если нажать на стрелку вправо, то будет двигаться круг, а квадрат двигаться не будет
4. если нажать на квадрат, то будет добавлено событие на нажатие кнопки для квадрата (но останется и событие на нажатие кнопки для круга)
5. если нажать стрелку вправо, то будут двигаться и круг и квадрат, потому что для каждого будет вызван соответствующий код

Например можно сделать так:

я добавил глобальную переменную `target` (дадада, глобальное - это не хорошо, но для демонстрации сойдет)

```
let target = '';
```

и когда вызывается метод `move` присваиваю `target` тип того объекта чей метод вызван:

```
target = this.type;
```

а уже внутри события нажатия кнопки отслеживаю а соответствует ли `target` типу объекта:

```
if (target != this.type)
    return;
```

в результате всегда двигается только 1 объект

```js
let target = '';

class Figure {
  constructor(type, name, styles) {
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
    this.styles = styles;
  }

  createFigure() {
    
    this.element = document.createElement('div');
    this.element.classList.add('el', `${this.type}`);
    this.element.style = `${this.css(this.styles)}`;
    this.element.dataset.name = this.name;

    this.element.addEventListener('click', () => this.move());

    let content = document.querySelector('#content');
    content.append(this.element);

  }

  move() {
    
    target = this.type;
    
    let y = 0;
    let x = 0;

    window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      
      if (target != this.type)
        return;
      
      const keyCode = event.code;
      
      switch (keyCode) {
        case 'ArrowDown':
          y++;
          this.element.style.top = y + 'px';
          break;
        case 'ArrowUp':
          y--;
          this.element.style.top = y + 'px';
          break;
        case 'ArrowLeft':
          x--;
          this.element.style.left = x + 'px';
          break;
        case 'ArrowRight':
          x++;
          this.element.style.left = x + 'px';
          break;
      }
    });
  }

  css(styles = {}) {
    if (typeof styles === 'string') return styles;
    return Object.keys(styles).map(key => `${key}: ${styles[key]}`).join(';');
  }

}

let a = new Figure('circle', 'Круг', {
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px',
    'border-radius': '50px',
    background: 'lightblue'
  }
);

let b = new Figure('square', 'Квадрат', {
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px',
    background: '#cccccc'
  }
);

a.createFigure();
b.createFigure();
```

```css
    #content {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .el {
        position: relative;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="app">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="panel"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: если ты несколько раз нажмешь на круг, каждый раз будет добавляться обработчик

Comment: @Zhihar спасибо большое за ответ. Можете посоветовать на что можно заменить глобальную переменную - target ?

Comment: @dredd_q, вот так схожу не скажу, вариантов много - можно создать синглтон для хранения данных, а можете сделать (попробовать, потому что не знаю насколько это для JS корректно) статическую переменную в классе чтоб ее мог менять любой экземпляр класса, в конце концов сделайте оболочку над экземплярами класса - например `class SeqFigures` внутри которого будет член `target` и массив из `Figure figures[]` - наверное это наиболее оправдано будет, поскольку все будет логически лежать на своих местах, кроме того тогда можно из этого класса-оболочки управлять сразу всеми объектами `Figure`

Comment: @Zhihar спасибо за вашу помощь еще раз))